# "Something went wrong" while running the App Script from Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I have a google sheet and created an app script by clicking on the extensions -> "Apps Script".
I imported the App Script in the Google sheets using Macro -> "Import Macro" and thus triggered it with the click of a button.

Everything works ok but when I share this sheet with editor access to a Microsoft account, the Microsoft account indeed can edit the content of the sheet but is not able to run the app script by clicking on the button.

First of all, sheet requests the permission to run the app script].

After clicking "Continue" it results in the error "Something went wrong".

[image]

Does Google not allow the running of scripts by a non-Google account user?
Is there any way to allow non-Google / workspace users to run the script?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Google not allow the running of scripts by a non-Google account user? Is there any way to allow non-Google / workspace users to run the script?

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is that in order to run a script the script needs to be authorised to run as *somebody*. If the person doesn't have a Google account then there is no account to authorise the script and so it can't be run.

Comment: Is there any alternative I can use?  basically, I need to send this data by making an API call to a backend server